# Adding an internal value to all woocommerce products

Tags: woocommerce

I simply want to add a field to all my products on woocommerce which isn't visible to customers.
This will be useful when exporting the product list to csv and calculating based on this value later.

Probably overlooked something obvious.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get all of your products. After that, check this meta key is already exists. If yes, then update the value; otherwise, add it as a new meta key.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$products = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();
    if(!empty(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_your_custom_meta_key', true))){
        update_post_meta($post->ID, '_your_custom_meta_key', 'Your custom value');
    }else{
        add_post_meta($post->ID, '_your_custom_meta_key', 'Your custom value');
    }
endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, under the admin section I have no way to add a field to products without editing the php?

Comment: Yes, you have the option. You can create a plugin where make an input field option and save it for future uses. Then you can update all products metadata by this data using the above code.